# Strange error when deploying ARM templates using DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an arm template which creates 2 document db servers. 
The section of the ARM template looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "[variables('sqlServerName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2019-12-12",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "tags": {
    "name": "Cosmos DB Account"
  },
  "properties": {
    "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard"
  }
},
{
  "name": "[variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "apiVersion": "2019-12-12",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "tags": {
    "name": "Cosmos Development DB Account"
  },
  "properties": {
    "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases",
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'), '/sql/', variables('name'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/', variables('sqlServerName'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "name": "[variables('liveName')]"
    },
    "options": {
      "throughput": "[variables('cosmosThroughPut')]"
    }
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases",
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName'), '/sql/', variables('name'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/', variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "name": "[variables('developmentName')]"
    },
    "options": {
      "throughput": "[variables('cosmosDevelopThroughPut')]"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'), '/sql/', variables('name'), '/', variables('cosmosContainerName'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases', variables('sqlServerName'), 'sql', variables('name'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "name": "[variables('cosmosContainerName')]",
      "partitionKey": {
        "paths": [
          "/categoryId"
        ],
        "kind": "Hash"
      },
      "indexingPolicy": {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "includedPaths": [{
          "path": "/*"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName'), '/sql/', variables('name'), '/', variables('cosmosContainerName'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
  "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases', variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName'), 'sql', variables('name'))]"],
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "name": "[variables('cosmosContainerName')]",
      "partitionKey": {
        "paths": [
          "/categoryId"
        ],
        "kind": "Hash"
      },
      "indexingPolicy": {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "includedPaths": [{
          "path": "/*"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the variables look like this:

```
"name": "sxp",
"sqlServerName": "[variables('liveName')]",
"sqlServerDevelopmentName": "[variables('developmentName')]",
"sxpDatabaseName": "[variables('name')]",
"cosmosContainerName": "products",
"cosmosThroughPut": "400",
"cosmosDevelopThroughPut": "400",
```

When I run my release I get this error (for both DocumentDb servers):

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
        "details": [
            {
                "code": "BadRequest",
                "message": "Message: {\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message: {\\\"partitionCount\\\":1}\\r\\nActivityId: b0751976-2076-4f29-93ab-b3d5849390b8, Request URI: /apps/0ccd856f-da7a-4ff9-a530-88ce0dbfd50c/services/b3350877-fd5e-4ea1-b6ee-41ecb9fb2540/partitions/14300278-223a-4614-afca-48f66e186695/replicas/132272757678585484p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2\"}, Request URI: /dbs, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.9.2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Which means absolutely nothing to me. I have tried googling it, but I can't find any reference to the error. The strange thing is, it creates the resources and they are usable, but the deployment says it has failed.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.
It's to do with the `id` property. You must have one. If you use the `arm-ttk-master` it will tell you that not using the **resourceId** function is not valid, but in the case for cosmos databases and containers, it is wrong.....

So, it should look like this:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases",
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName'), '/sql/', variables('name'))]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('sqlServerDevelopmentName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "id": "[variables('name')]"
    },
    "options": {
      "throughput": "[variables('cosmosDevelopThroughPut')]"
    }
  }
},
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('sqlServerName'), '/sql/', variables('name'), '/', variables('cosmosContainerName'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers",
  "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases', variables('sqlServerName'), 'sql', variables('name'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "resource": {
      "id": "[variables('cosmosContainerName')]",
      "partitionKey": {
        "paths": [
          "/categoryId"
        ],
        "kind": "Hash"
      },
      "indexingPolicy": {
        "indexingMode": "consistent",
        "includedPaths": [{
          "path": "/*"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
},
```

take note of the id properties:

```
"id": "[variables('cosmosContainerName')]",
```

Comment: If this solves the issue, I suggest you mark it as answer.

Comment: I would, but I can't mark it as the answer until Saturday as I answered it